# AWS SDK GetBucketPolicy returns different JSON schema than what is in S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Following is the Policy json I generated using :

```
    {
    "Id": "Policy1564102281945",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S1001",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<>/*",
            "Principal": {
                **"AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<>:root"
                ]**
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I use the AWS SDK for C# and call the following API

```
client.GetBucketPolicy(bucketName)
```

I get the following Json response.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1564102281945",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "S1001",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                **"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::185160002363:root"**
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mcafee-mvision-epo-dev-girish-cda/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the JSON schema at "AWS" object. In the S3 "Bucket Policy" tap "AWS" is actually an array. But in the API response it is embedded as an object in "Principal".

This happens only when there is one ARN added in the list. If there are at least 2 elements, then the API responds with an array for "AWS" object.

Any reason for this inconsistency? 
Is it expected that clients handle this using Object type check when converted into JSON using any library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not unique to `Principal`. The same thing happens whenever you are trying to create array with just one item in policy. Look at `Action` in your policy.

You have defined:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
],
```

but the result is

```
"Action": "s3:GetObject"
```

This happens internally on AWS side when you submit put policy request, each array with one value is replaced with just that value. As for why, I guess that AWS wants to minimize size of the policy.

As for the inconsistency between Console view and what you see, there is none, all you need to do is to refresh the tab to see the newly formatted policy. This is just because you are submitting the unformatted policy and your tab is not automatically refreshed with the value that is actually stored on AWS backend.

And yes, if you are fetching policy through CLI/SDK and converting it to JSON then you need to be aware of this and handle it accordingly.